# Generate *.pom file into target directory

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-install-plugin

I would like to deploy couple parent pom's into Nexus. I know about `mvn deploy`, but I need *.pom files in `target/` or somewhere else. 
Is there a simple solution (maybe maven plugin) to generate a *.pom file in target/ or I need execute `mvn install` and get it from local `.m2`?

```
repo-A/
  pom.xml
  repo-B/
    pom.xml
  repo-C/
    pom.xml
```

All pom's has `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.

Comment: Why do you need them in target folder? If those are parents a simple `mvn deploy` will do the needed things..?

Comment: I have to use Nexus Artifact Uploader. It gets artifacts from target, so I decide to create one config for pom/jar.

Comment: If you run your build in Jenkins better use Maven itself to upload the artifacts to your repository manager than jenkins plugins make it harder than needed.

Comment: Finally I have accept to moved to `mvn deploy`, so the all problems should be resolved. Thanks